# Draw horizontal linear gradient inside shape

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-graphics

I have the following code that draws a triangle based on some given angle.
How do I fill this shape with a linear (horizontal) gradient?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Create Lines
    CGPoint startPt = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.frame.size.height);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, width_);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.center.x, self.center.y);
    CGPoint addLines[] =
    {
        startPt,
        CGPointMake(radius_ * cos(angle_) + startPt.x, radius_ * sin(angle_) + startPt.y),
        CGPointMake(radius_ * cos(angle_) + startPt.x, startPt.y),
        startPt
    };

    CGContextAddLines(context, addLines, sizeof(addLines)/sizeof(addLines[0]));
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the shape as a clipping path and then fill the shape's bounding box with a gradient. After that stroke it.